# Перегрузка операторов шаблонного класса C++

Tags: c++, ооп, шаблоны-с++, перегрузка-операторов

Есть такой класс:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename Type>
class TVector;

template<typename Type>
ostream & operator<< (ostream & output, const TVector<Type>& object)
{
    for (int i = 0; i != object.size; i++)
    {
        output << object.ptr[i] << "    ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return output;
}

template<typename Type>
istream & operator >> (istream & input, TVector<Type> & obj)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < obj.size; i++)
        input >> obj.ptr[i];
    return input;
}


template <typename Type>
class TVector
{
    Type * ptr;
    int size;
public:

TVector()
{
    size = 3;
    ptr = new Type[size];
    for (int i = 0; i != size; i++)
    {
        //ptr[i] = 0.0;
    }
}

TVector(int size_)
{
    size = size_;
    ptr = new Type[size];
    for (int i = 0; i != size; i++)
    {
        ptr[i] = 0.0;
    }
}


TVector (const TVector<Type>& other)
{
    size = other.size;
    ptr = new Type[size];
    for (size_t i = 0; i != size; ++i)
        ptr[i] = other.ptr[i];

    return *this;
}

//template<typename Type>
int get_size()
{
    return size;
}

template<typename Type>
void cmultiply(Type x)
{
    for (int i = 0; i != size; i++)
    {
        this->ptr[i] *= x;
    }
}

template<typename Type>
void sum(TVector<Type>& other)
{
    try {
        if (this->size == other.size)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i != size; i++)
                this->ptr[i] += other.ptr[i];
        }
        else
        {
            throw "size error";
        }
    }
    catch (char *str)
    {
        cout << str << endl;
    }
}

template<typename Type>
Type smultiply(TVector<Type>& other)
{
    try {
        if (this->size == other.size)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i != size; i++)
            {
                this->ptr[i] *= other.ptr[i];
            }
            double S = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i != size; i++)
            {
                S += this->ptr[i];
            }
            return S;
        }
        else {
            throw "size error";
        }
    }
    catch (char * str)
    {
        cout << str;
    }
}


void show()
{
    for (int i = 0; i != size; i++)
    {
        cout << ptr[i] << "    ";
    }
    cout << '\n';
}


Type & operator[](int num)
{
    try {
        if ((num >= 0) && (num < size))
            return ptr[num];
        else
            throw "size error";
    }
    catch (char *str)
    {
        cout << str << endl;
    }
}

template<typename Type>
bool operator==(const TVector<Type>& other)
{
    if (size != other.size)
        return false;
    else
        for (int i = 0; i != size; i++)
        {
            if (this->ptr[i] != other.ptr[i])
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    return true;
}

template<typename Type>
bool operator!=(int)
{
    if (this == NULL)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}

template<typename Type>
bool operator!=(const TVector<Type>& other)
{
    return !(*this == other);
}

template<typename Type>
TVector<Type>& operator+(const TVector<Type>& other)
{
    if (size != other.size)
    {
        cout << "wrong sizes";
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        for (int i = 0; i != size; i++)
            this->ptr[i] += other.ptr[i];
    return (*this);
}


template<typename Type>
TVector<Type>& operator+=(const TVector<Type>& other)
{
    if (size != other.size)
        exit(1);
    else
        return(*this + other);
}

template<typename Type>
TVector<Type>& operator-(const TVector<Type>& other)
{
    if (size != other.size)
    {
        cout << "wrong sizes";
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        for (int i = 0; i != size; i++)
            this->ptr[i] -= other.ptr[i];
    return (*this);
}

template<typename Type>
TVector<Type>& operator-=(const TVector<Type>& other)
{
    if (size != other.size)
        exit(1);
    else
        return(*this - other);
}

template<typename Type>
TVector<Type>& operator*(const TVector<Type>& other)
{
    if (size != other.size)
        exit(1);
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i != size; i++)
        {
            this->ptr[i] *= other.ptr[i];
        }
    }
    return *this;
}

template<typename Type>
TVector<Type>& operator*(double x)
{
    for (int i = 0; i != size; i++)
    {
        ptr[i] *= x;
    }
    return *this;
}

template<typename Type>
TVector<Type>& operator*=(const TVector<Type>& other)
{
    if (size != other.size)
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        return ((*this)*other);
    }
}

template<typename Type>
TVector<Type>& operator=(const TVector<Type>& other)
{
    if (&other != this)
    {
        if (size != other.size)
        {
            delete[] ptr;
            size = other.size;
            ptr = new Type[size];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i != size; i++)
            ptr[i] = other.ptr[i];
    }
    return *this;
}


friend ostream & ::operator<< <Type> (ostream & output, const TVector<Type>& object);



friend istream & operator >> <Type> (istream & input, TVector<Type> & obj);


~TVector()
{
    delete[]ptr;
}
};
```

Перегруженные операторы в приведенном коде работают только для одинаковых типов.

Вопрос: как правильно перегрузить операции *, -, + , чтобы можно оперировать векторами разных типов? Например:

```
TVector<complex<double>> b(3);
TVector<double> a(3)
TVector <complex<double>> c = a + b;
```

Comment: А что говорит компилятор когда вы так пишите?

Comment: @PavelMayorov
Ошибка C2248 TVector<double>::size: невозможно обратиться к private член, объявленному в классе "TVector<double>

Ошибка C2440 return: невозможно преобразовать "TVector<std::complex<double>>" в "TVector<double> &". Ошибки возникают в операторе +

Comment: Ну так объявите разные специализации векторов дружественными друг другу...

Answer (score -1):

Проблема для вас здесь:

```
template<typename Type>
TVector<Type>& operator+(const TVector<Type>& other)
```

Как можно заметить `type this` и `type other` одинаковые, а надо:

```
template<typename Type, typename Type_other>
TVector<Type>& operator+(const TVector<Type_other>& other)
```

И так для всех методов

Comment: `typename Type` тут не нужен - Type уже объявлен на уровне класса

Comment: @PavelMayorov это не имеет отношения к проблеме. Я скопировал этот код с вопроса, и почему там так сделано я без понятия. Если у вас вопросы то это к вопросу. Более того мне вообще не ясно почему вы решили что что-то где-то объявлено. Это отрывок кода из которого вообще ничего не следует. Он даже не скомпилиться сам по себе.

Comment: Нет, это как раз имеет отношение к проблеме. Пожалуйста, изучите код из вопроса внимательнее.

Comment: До сих пор непонятно откуда ты из отрывка кода увидел объявление класса например. А раз вы мне предлагаете изучить код вопроса повнимательней, то может сами и опубликуете ответ? Или вы пока только комментировать хотите?

Comment: @AndrioSkur Так в том то и дело, что в вопросе объявлен, а у вас нет. Новичка это введет в заблуждение.

Comment: Там в вопросе есть строчки `template <typename Type> class TVector {`, и все операторы кроме двух объявлены внутри.

Comment: Что же до своего ответа - нет, писать его у меня желания нет. А комментировать - есть. И это не запрещено.